# why is the function code not working

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

Am trying to get a function call but i cant get it to print. Please help here.
This is the code:

```
def foo():
    name = input ('>>').lower().split()
    for item in name:
        if name == foo:
            print ('foo here!')
    else:
        bar()
def bar(): 
    name = input ('>>').lower().split()
    for item in name:
        if name == bar:
            print ('bar here!')


def start():
    print('Welcome Home')
    name = input
    foo()


start()
```

Comment: What do you want this to do? Just from reading the code I'd say that "if name == foo" is probably not what you want (in the definition of foo), it compares "name" (which is a list of strings) with "foo" (a function object) and those will never compare equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `print ('foo here!')` and `print ('bar here!')` are not executed because the boolean expressions `name == foo` and `name == bar` are evaluated to false in most cases. For instance, in the boolean expression `name == foo` under the definition `foo()`, the first element of the list `name` is compared with `foo`. `foo` returns a friendly string representation of the object function `foo()` (usually used for debugging purposes). You can actually try and print `foo()` by executing `print(foo)` and assign the returned value to the list `name` in `foo()` (in my case its `<function foo at 0x7fad58f35d40>` – it will probably be different in your machine). This will evaluate `name == foo` to true and hence will result in `print ('foo here!')` being executed. That being said, [here is how for loop works](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm):

[image]

The first element in your `name` list is assigned to the `item` variable. Next, the body of the for loop is executed. After the body is executed, the second element in the list `name` is assigned to the variable `item` before the body of the for loop is executed again. This process continues until there are no more elements in the `name` list. Now in order for say `print('foo here!')` to be executed, the boolean expression in your if statement has to be evaluated to true.

Here is an example where `print('foo here!')` will execute when the user types foo after running the program.

```
def foo():
    name = input('>>').lower().split()

    for item in name:
        if item == 'foo':
            print('foo here!')
        else:
            bar()

def bar():
    name = input('>>').lower().split()

    for item in name:
        if item == 'bar':
            print('bar here!')

print('Welcome Home')
foo()
```

In the definition `foo()`, the first element of the list `name` is compared with the [string](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm) foo, thus the condition `if name == 'foo'` is met. Here is a sample of the execution:

```
[firas@arch Python]$ ./foobar.py 
Welcome Home
>>foo
foo here!
```